# How to Display "title" and "displayvalue" from smart sheets using the cURL code shown below?

Tags: api, curl, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-1.1

```
curl https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/5848567060424580/columns/4140686686611332 -H "Authorization: Bearer 21txb6n2ajlf6dhsil8g3jxtdu"
```

^^^^That is the curl command i put into the terminal and when i do, i get this information poster below. The access token: 21txb6n2ajlf6dhsil8g3jxtdu & Sheet ID:5848567060424580. I want to get a curl command that only displays certain values instead of every single ID and formatting option in the columns from the Smartsheet. Any help would be useful thanks!

{"id":4140686686611332,"index":2,"title":"Column3","type":"TEXT_NUMBER","width":150}MAC-C02Q3C5MG8WP:~ jxs18$ curl https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/584856724580 -H "Authorization: Bearer 21txb6n2ajlf6dhsil8g3jxtdu"
{"id":5848567060424580,"name":"JagTestSheet","version":1,"totalRowCount":3,"accessLevel":"EDITOR_SHARE","effectiveAttachmentOptions":["FILE","ONEDRIVE","GOOGLE_DRIVE","EVERNOTE","BOX_COM","EGNYTE","DROPBOX"],"ganttEnabled":false,"dependenciesEnabled":false,"resourceManagementEnabled":false,"cellImageUploadEnabled":true,"userSettings":{"criticalPathEnabled":false,"displaySummaryTasks":true},"permalink":"https://app.smartsheet.com/b/home?lx=PoM3LKb9HF6g_jsJ9JoWwg","createdAt":"2016-07-07T14:44:38Z","modifiedAt":"2016-07-07T15:22:53Z","columns":[{"id":1888886872926084,"index":0,"title":"Primary Column","type":"TEXT_NUMBER","primary":true,"width":150},{"id":6392486500296580,"index":1,"title":"Column2","type":"TEXT_NUMBER","width":150},{"id":4140686686611332,"index":2,"title":"Column3","type":"TEXT_NUMBER","width":150},{"id":8644286313981828,"index":3,"title":"Column4","type":"TEXT_NUMBER","width":150},{"id":481511989372804,"index":4,"title":"Column5","type":"TEXT_NUMBER","width":150},{"id":4985111616743300,"index":5,"title":"Column6","type":"TEXT_NUMBER","width":150}],"rows":[{"id":6858731183990660,"rowNumber":1,"expanded":true,"createdAt":"2016-07-07T15:22:53Z","modifiedAt":"2016-07-07T15:22:53Z","cells":[{"columnId":1888886872926084,"value":234.0,"displayValue":"234"},{"columnId":6392486500296580,"value":657.0,"displayValue":"657"},{"columnId":4140686686611332,"value":875.0,"displayValue":"875"},{"columnId":8644286313981828},{"columnId":481511989372804},{"columnId":4985111616743300}]},{"id":1229231649777540,"rowNumber":2,"siblingId":6858731183990660,"expanded":true,"createdAt":"2016-07-07T15:22:53Z","modifiedAt":"2016-07-07T15:22:53Z","cells":[{"columnId":1888886872926084,"value":564.0,"displayValue":"564"},{"columnId":6392486500296580,"value":546.0,"displayValue":"546"},{"columnId":4140686686611332,"value":453.0,"displayValue":"453"},{"columnId":8644286313981828},{"columnId":48151198937280MAC-C02Q3C5MG8WP:

Comment: If the token posted in the question is a valid token, please revoke it ASAP to prevent any security compromise of your Smartsheet account.

Comment: the sheet id is a sample one for which the token is being used for, there is no integral information on that sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider piping the output into something like [jsawk](https://github.com/micha/jsawk)
to query the JSON response for what you are looking for from your cURL request.

Comment: I want to only display the display value of cells which have data in them though, I want to know how to do that!